# XMLDOM with Microsoft Edge

Tags: javascript, dom, microsoft-edge

I'm having a very simple but frustrating issue with XMLDOM and Microsoft Edge browser. I've been looking over the current documentation but I'm not seeing anything on functionality this legacy. In our code base, we have a function whos job is to return an XMLDOM object. The function does this -

```
if(activeXDetected()) {
   domObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
} else {
   domObject = document.implementation.createDocument(...);
}
```

I wasn't expecting ActiveX support in Edge, but I was hoping that the pattern would fall back to the same pattern used by almost every other browser (document.implementation....). In this use case though, with edge browser the there is no loadXML method in the returned object at all, and as far as I can tell what you're getting back (and you do get an object back) seems to be a generic dom object.

How does one get a XMLDOM object back with all supported methods et. al.

Answer (score -1):

what is `activeXDetected()`?

use feature detection instead

```
if(ActiveXObject) {
   domObject = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLDOM");
} else {
   domObject = document.implementation.createDocument(...);
}
```

Comment: The code is as follows - 

return (window.ActiveXObject || window.ActiveXObject !== undefined);

this methodology is required for proper detection in IE11. Your posted version was actually failing in IE11, you actually need to do a typed check for undefined.

I'm pretty sure that failing on active x detection in Edge is right and proper.